# I need more voltage!

Tags: power-supply, voltage

How do I build a circuit to operate a 220 VAC power supply from USA AC mains?

I couldn't find this question anywhere else, so please forgive me if this is a duplicate. I need to run a power supply unit that needs 205 volts to start up. However, I live in the USA, so I don't normally have that type of voltage. What do I need to do to be able to power this PSU?

Power Supply [**BITMAIN APW3-12-1600-B2**](https://bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=000201505040743496917U7kGsCm0694)

```
Input Voltage Range - 176-264 VAC    
   Starting Voltage - 200-205 VAC  
    Frequency Range -  47-63  Hz
```

Comment: What device do you have that need 205 VAC (I assume) to start up?

Comment: @Tyler https://bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=000201505040743496917U7kGsCm0694

Comment: 120 to 240 converter...

Comment: You actually need less voltage, you are going to be powering this off of a 240 VAC circuit, right?

Comment: Use a standard 220V circuit. 120 VAC (standard house plug) won't work. If you don't have a 220 outlet available (and it's usually used for electric dryers) you'll need an electrician to install one - but it's a pretty standard job so you don't need a specialist.

Comment: @Tyler I need to use that Power Supply to power a computer. I don't think I have the 205V to start it up. That is all I know. I don't know that much about electricity.

Comment: Standard US home power supply is 240VAC center tapped - 120V line to neutral, 240V line to line (despite the number of people that call it 110/220, which it's not, unless there's a brownout...)

Comment: What others have recommended - using two "phases", if available, is THE best and easiest solution for you. WARNING - ground/chassis connection needs to be checked. Input to output SHOULD be isolated but is not specifically mentioned in the spec. The manufacturer knows. | The next best choice is a 2:1 step up transformer. Your supply's Vinmax  = 264 AC so a 220-240 VAC line is "OK". | eg ebay has numerous possible choices. This supply - see next comment for link -  would PROBABLY do OK. It's 1500 VA rated which is ABOUT what you need at full load.

Comment: [**This one**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GE-9T58B53-1-5-KVA-1-5KVA-220-230-340-440-460-480-110-115-120-1PH-TRANSFORMER/231744571871?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D35389%26meid%3Dd3b8a2f73b8542618ca45389b6a85088%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D231633914479)

Answer (score 2):

The Power Supply (PSU) that you linked to runs off a typical 220 to 250 volts AC (VAC), and not the standard 110 - 120VAC you get at a North American home outlet. However, your home likely does have the necessary 220 to 240VAC at the circuit breaker panel as most homes do have a single 220-240VAC circuit plus a neutral line (called split-phase AC)

This image is from Wikipedia - [Split-Phase Electric Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power)

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/29/Split_phase2.png))</sub>

Across the V1 and V2 lines from the image above, you see that you have 240VAC. In a North American home, this 240VAC is usually brought out to the electric dryer and electric stove in the kitchen.

What you will need to do is find another PSU that runs off of 120VAC, or use a 120 to 240VAC converter (rated for 1800W at least, to cover the necessary 1600W power rating of the PSU) or hire an electrician to give you access to a 240VAC circuit (maybe in the garage?) to run that PSU. I do not recommend making any electrical wiring changes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Run the supply on 240 volts - available from two adjacent breakers (or a two-pole breaker) in your breaker panel.

Since it is rated at 1600 watts, it can't be run on a common 15 Amp 120 volt circuit.

Comment: 120 VAC x 15A  1800VA. 110VAC x 15A = 165-0 VA. What am I missing about US supplies?